# Spring mvc 5.2.0 + RabbtMQ + Camel - CamelContext must be specified Exception

Tags: spring-mvc, rabbitmq, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am trying to use Camel with rabbitMQ in Spring MVC the following way:

camel-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
          http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <routeBuilder ref="routeBuilder" />
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

the routeBuilder class:

```
@Service(value = "routeBuilder")
public class CamelContextRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Value("${flag:true}")
    private boolean flag;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{
        if (flag) {
            createRoutes();
        }
    }

    private void createRoutes() {
        from(String.format("spring-amqp:...))
                .throttle(...).timePeriodMillis(...)
                .bean("msgProcessor");
    }
}
```

and the processor class:

```
@Component(value = "msgProcessor")
public class MsgProcessor implements Processor {

    public MsgProcessor() {}

    @Override
    public void process(final Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Message message = exchange.getMessage();
        ...
    }
}
```

the dependencies are:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bluelock</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

I manage to build the project and run it, I see the rabbit queue has consumers so the routes are created but when a message is processed (failed to get to the listener), the following exception is thrown:

> CamelContext must be specified on: Message[]
>
> {"filename":"CamelLogger.java","lineno":"213","stacktrace":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
>
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1498)
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1409)
> at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1329)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
> at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor$MethodInvocationRetryCallback.doWithRetry(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:229)
> at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:286)
> at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:210)
> at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:173)

> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\n\tat
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\n\tat
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.$Proxy342.invokeListener(Unknown
> Source)\n\tat
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1316)\n\tat
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1295)\n\tat
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:746)\n\tat
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:730)\n\tat
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:74)\n\tat
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:946)\n\tat
> amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPConsumer$SpringAMQPExecutorTask.run(SpringAMQPConsumer.java:316)\n\tat
> amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPConsumer$SpringAMQPExecutorTask.run(SpringAMQPConsumer.java:316)\n\tat
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CamelContext must be specified on:
> Message[]\n\tat
> org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(ObjectHelper.java:340)\n\tat
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage.createHeaders(DefaultMessage.java:255)\n\tat
> org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage.getHeaders(DefaultMessage.java:216)\n\tat
> amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPHeader.setBasicPropertiesToHeaders(SpringAMQPHeader.java:61)\n\tat
> amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPMessage.fromAMQPMessage(SpringAMQPMessage.java:53)\n\tat
> amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPConsumer$RabbitMQMessageListener.onMessage(SpringAMQPConsumer.java:197)\n\tat
> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1406)\n\t...
> 24
> more","level":"WARN","exception_class":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException","logger_name":"amqp.spring.camel.component.SpringAMQPConsumer","thread":"SpringAMQPConsumer.SpringAMQPExecutor-5","message":"Caused
> by:
> [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException
>
> - Listener threw exception]","timestamp":"2020-10-30 14:29:48,876","exception_message":"Listener threw exception"}

```
Where does the CamelContext usage is missing?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, using the following connection:

```
from("spring-amqp"...)
```

is a deprecated package:

```
<groupId>com.bluelock</groupId>
```

removing it and using the following instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

```
from("rabbitmq:...")
```

solved the issue.